# ASP.NET Core/Angular 2 - ts an HTML changes are not being reflected in any browser

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core/Angular project. I don't understand why browsers are not pulling the last version of my JavaScript. Yet when I look at the output folder (**wwwwroot/ClientApp/app**), all the JavaScript files and their corresponding map files are up to date.

I've pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Refresh</kbd> to force browsers to request newer version, but nothing is happening. They still have the older versions. Same is true with the **HTML**.

The MVC part works just fine, i.e. any change is being reflected by the browser.

What else can be done to push browsers to refresh the pages?

Comment: I checked the "disable cache" checkbox but with not success. That's so annoying.

Comment: make sure the dev tools is open while you refresh the page

Comment: I did, but still no luck. it still not updating.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue with HTML files especially -

While in development, you can set the browser to disable the cache when dev tools are open

1 - Right Click Inspect element OR `Ctrl + Shift + I`

2 - Go to settings

[image]

3 - Disable the cache when Dev Tools is open

[image]

you could also see if the checkbox is checked under network tab Also you can disable the cache under Network tab to force a refresh

[image]

after disabling the cache keep Dev tools open and refresh the page

Comment: I've done what you suggested, unfortunately it still not pulling the last version.

Comment: I've decided to move my application to Visual studio code until I find out what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

remove your browser cookies and cache, or try this:
use another browser
change app url or port so the browser will retrieve a fresh resources